# Multiple Schema.org ItemList elements on one page

Tags: schema.org, rdfa

I defined multiple ItemLists on one page, and the Chrome extension *Structured Data Testing Tool* says: "ITEMLISTS_MULTIPLE_LISTS_ON_PAGE"

> [image: Error for ItemList markup in the Chrome extension 'Structured Data Testing Tool']

Is there any way to define multiple `ItemList` elements within one page while being still valid?

```html
<div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="ItemList">
 <h2 property="name">Top 10 laptops</h2><br>
 <link property="itemListOrder" href="http://schema.org/ItemListOrderDescending" />
 <p>1. <span property="itemListElement">HP Pavilion dv6-6013cl</span></p>
 <p>2. <span property="itemListElement">Dell XPS 15 (Sandy Bridge)</span></p>
 <p>3. <span property="itemListElement">Lenovo ThinkPad X220</span></p>
 ...
</div>

<div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="ItemList">
 <h2 property="name">Top 10 tablets</h2><br>
 <link property="itemListOrder" href="http://schema.org/ItemListOrderDescending" />
 <p>1. <span property="itemListElement">Apple iPad</span></p>
 <p>2. <span property="itemListElement">Samsung Galaxy Tab S3</span></p>
 <p>3. <span property="itemListElement">Asus ZenPad 3S 10</span></p>
 ...
</div>
```

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: This answer on Webmasters which might be helpful: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/122513/multiple-schema-org-itemlists

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't allow this.
What one could do is create an ItemList for the `h2` items and create intermediary pages per `h2` element